# Assign a value to a variable inside a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I want to assign a value to my variable inside a CTE and use it in my next CTE.

Is it possible?

```
declare @TypeQty as int
;
With CTE1 as
(@TypeQty = (select Count(ID) as MyQty from MyTbl))
,CTE2 as
(select * from MyTbl2 where Qty= @TypeQty)
Select * from CTE2
```

I know it possible with some way else, but I want to know is it possible with CTE or not?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can't use this syntax as you wrote in the question.

You can use the calculated value without the variable, just by referencing the CTE itself. Something like this:

```
WITH
CTE1
as
(
    select Count(ID) as MyQty
    from MyTbl
)
,CTE2
as
(
    select *
    from
        MyTbl2
        INNER JOIN CTE1 ON MyTbl2.Qty = CTE1.MyQty
)
Select *
from CTE2
;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is explicitly not allowed in SQL Server.  A query either returns a result set or (exclusively) assigns variables, but not both.

I do wonder why you would use either CTEs or variables for this example.  A simple subquery seems simple enough:

```
Select t2.*
from MyTbl2 t2
where t2.qty = (select count(*) from mytable t);
```

CTEs in SQL Server do not offer performance benefits.  And I don't see any "clarity-of-code" benefits to using them in this case.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible to populate variables inside a cte query definition.

The cte query definition must return a result set, and it's impossible to do both in T-SQL - a `select` statement can either return a result set or populate variables - but not both at the same time.

Therefor, it's impossible to populate variable inside a common table expression query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBQUERY` Instead of using `Recursive CTE`

```
SELECT * FROM MYTBL2 M
INNER JOIN(
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS MYQTY FROM MYTBL) S ON M.QTY=S.MYQTY
```